# cupy.full() method fill_value can't take an array?

Tags: python, numpy, cupy

I noticed that the `fill_value` argument in `numpy.full()` can be an array.

```
>>> a = np.arange(5)
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> b = np.full( (5,10), a[:,None], dtype=np.int16 )
>>> b
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]], dtype=int16)
```

However, I noticed the `fill_value` argument in CuPy can't.

```
>>> b_gpu = cp.full( (5,10), a[:,None], dtype=np.int16 )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 1, in <module>
    b_gpu = cp.full( (5,10), a[:,None], dtype=np.int16 )
  File "/home/master/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cupy/creation/basic.py", line 271, in full
    a.fill(fill_value)
  File "cupy/core/core.pyx", line 499, in cupy.core.core.ndarray.fill
  File "cupy/core/core.pyx", line 510, in cupy.core.core.ndarray.fill
ValueError: non-scalar numpy.ndarray cannot be used for fill
```

Is there a functionality missing or do I have an error in the way I have written CuPy?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to use `cp.repeat` and `reshape` to reproduce `b = np.full( (5,10), a[:,None], dtype=np.int16 )` in GPU.

```
>>> b_gpu = cp.repeat( a, 10 ).reshape(5,10)
>>> b_gpu
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]])
```